# Turn R output into a dataframe of multiple vectors

Tags: r, dataframe

The standard bit of code below from the VARS package forecasts values for several variables.
What I want to do is to take those values and turn them into a data frame so I can produce time series graphs.

```
> predict(var4, n.ahead=12, ci=0.95)
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is highly vague. I suppose you're looking for:

```
x <- predict(var4, n.ahead=12, ci=0.95)
data.frame(n = rep(names(x), each = nrow(x$fcst[[1]])), do.call(rbind, x$fcst))
```

By the way: The package's name is `vars`, not `VARS`.